# Is it necessary to calculate Cronbach’s alpha for each sub-test?

Tags: spss, likert, reliability, scales, cronbachs-alpha

I have a data set that includes two sub-tests, each measured using a Likert scale. I want to test the reliability.

Is it necessary to calculate Cronbach’s alpha for each sub-test? Or do I have to calculate just one Cronbach’s alpha coefficient for all the data?

Comment: What are you hoping the Cronbach Alpha to inform you on?

Comment: testing reliability of a questionnaire

Comment: Alpha measures the degree of inter-item homogeneity; it is like split-half reliability. I expect that it is within sub-tests only, not throughout the entire questionnaire, that homogeneity should hold. If so, do for each sub-test.

Answer (score 1):

Calculating the alpha separately for each sub-test isn't ideal, as it misses how the measure as a whole may be poor and lead to attentuation bias in the estimates of whatever model you are using.

Based on your question, it sounds like you believe that the tau-equivalence assumption is unmet with your construct and you require something that captures multi-dimensional measurement better. For that purpose, it may be better to use McDonald's omega unidimensional, $\omega_u$, or McDonald's omega hierarchical, $\omega_h$, to measure reliability.

We obtain $\omega_u$ when we assume that tau equivalence may not be equal but that overall the items measure one construct. We measure $\omega_h$ when we believe that the construct is necessarily observed by multiple factors such as the case you lay out. Both are measured with a factor analysis-based method of measurement and can be easily attained in programs like R. If $\omega_u$ is poor, it is often the result of bad items or a multi-dimensional construct such as yours, so $\omega_h$ may be better suited for your purpose.

For more information about what this reliability coefficient does and how to compute it, please refer to [this useful article](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/full/10.1177/2515245920951747).